# Delphi MediaPlayer adjust size

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have a simple form that loads and plays a video using the media player, and media player control components. Is there a way to resize the video played, using a scrollbar or something similar in RAD Studio XE6.

Comment: Which platform? And resize with a scroll bar. I've never come across that UI before. Are you sure that's what you meant? And are you struggling to use scroll bars? Or finding how to resize? I'd guess the latter, in which case it is distracting to talk about scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing is usually done by resizing the form hosting the viewport, not with scrollbars. Try putting the media player in a sizable form or panel with anchors on all four sides so it expands and contracts as you adjust the corners of the form.

Comment: Ok lets forget the scrollbars, I just said that in the hopes of painting a better picture. Lets say that I am playing a video that is 340x180 and I want to make it twice as big, or zoom in x2, so the new video dimensions will be 680x360. I can't find any similar option in the embarcadero documentation.

Comment: Put it in a panel, set it to Align with Client, then set the panel's dimensions. I don't know if it will let you scale it other than proportionally or not, but it's easy for you to test within the IDE. Just change the panel's Height and/or Width and see what happens. Let us know.

Comment: I am not sure if I did everything as I was supposed to but the behaviour of the video is as follows. If i resize the panel and make it smaller than my original video dimensions then the video will follow. If again I make the panel bigger the video will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement sort of ZoomIn or ZoomOut functionalitay by adjusting the DisplayRect property:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.DisplayRect

First you would probably want to set DisplayRect to the size of the control/component which you have selected as rendering target using Display property:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.Display

In order to avoid uneven wideo streching I recomend you add necessary code to be able to calculate proper DisplayRect dimensions while maintaing aspect ratio.

If you want you can make DisplayRect even larger than your rendering conroll. By doing this you realy achieve that ZoomIn effect.

Do note that this only strectches the video content so you may expirience loss of quality, becouse TMediaPlayer doesen't use any special filters for doing so as many comercial Media Players do.

EDIT: I don't have expirience about using of TMediaPlayer on FireMonkey platform but after looking at documentation it seems that things have been changed quite a bit.

For instance on FMX there is special component called TMediaPlayerControll which is required for rendering video on.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayerControl

But looking at documentation I can't find any special properties or methods to controll the video size. So I gues that implementing of ZoomIn or ZoomOut functionality would be using the same approach as it can be used with normal FireMonkex components.

Comment: I noticed that the parent in this example is a vcl component while I am using FireMonkey, could this be the reason why the DisplayRect property doesn't  exist error appears?

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you are working on FireMonkey platform. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Indeed I should have mentioned i was not using VCL. Could you possibly give an example though, as I am very new to using Delphi and RAD Studio.

Comment: I'll try to make one when I get home since I don't have acces to my development computer right not. In the mean time check the FMX.MediaPlayerHD example that ships with Delphi and is located inside samples folder to get mocre information about this. If you haven't installed Samples with your Delphi you can get that specific example from: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/FMX.MediaPlayerHD_Sample

Comment: Sure, before I asked I checked the examples folder. Also tried applying some effects, like Invert or Magnify from the Tool Palette, but with no results.

Comment: After banging my head for about an hour the only way to strech the video output when using TMediaPlayer on FireMonkey platform that I found is placing the TMediaPlayerControl on a panel and then scaling that panel in order to stretch its context to fit the desired size. But this is a bit cumberstone solution as you might need to dynamically change the Panels position so that desired part of it is always visible.

Comment: Please check my comment on Davids' answer. Also I'm a bit confused, should I accept the answer or it would be better if you edited it saying that it's not possible?

Comment: I just thought of another possibility, using ffplay to play the video. It has the ability to scale it depending on the window size, the thing is that it plays the video in an external window and not inside the main form.

Comment: @dearn44 As far as accepting the answer goes: I ask you to wait a bit. I still have a few ideas I would like to try.

As far as using of ffplay goes: As far as I know ffplay always creats its own window and desen't support rendering to existing windows. I might be wrong on this.